# ¿Cómo controlar (xml) el ancho del spinner dentro de un GridLayout en Android?

Tags: android, xml, spinner

Tengo una pantalla que consiste en un GridLayout de 13x3. He incluido TextView descriptivos a la izquierda (1ra columna) para los EditText a la derecha (columnas 2 y 3).

Al incluir controles de tipo Spinner en las filas inferiores, desde la columna 2 a la 3, estos no se acoplan al GridLayout, exceden el margen derecho de la pantalla y a la vez hacen que los EditText de las primeras filas excedan igualmente el margen derecho de la pantalla. Estos controles de tipo input ocupan las columnas 2 y 3 de mi GridLayout.

¿Con qué atributos y valores puedo lograr que mis Spinners se adecuen al tamaño de la pantalla y no sobresalgan de esta?

Este es el xml:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:rowCount="13"
        tools:context="on_site_sampling.com.on_sitesampling.Settings">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:text="@string/settings"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    />

    <TextView
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:text="@string/username"
    />

    <EditText
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/usernameEditText"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:hint="USERNAME"
        android:inputType="text"
    />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:paddingBottom="5sp"
        android:paddingTop="10sp"
        android:text="@string/ftp_connection_settings"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    />

    <TextView
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:text="@string/host"
    />

    <EditText
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/hostEditText"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:hint="HOST"
        android:inputType="text"
    />

    <TextView
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:text="@string/user"
    />

    <EditText
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/userEditText"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:hint="USER"
        android:inputType="text"
    />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:text="@string/password"
        android:textSize="14sp"
    />

    <EditText
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:hint="PASSWORD"
        android:inputType="text"
    />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_columnSpan="3"
        android:paddingBottom="5sp"
        android:paddingTop="10sp"
        android:text="@string/screen_preferences"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    />

    <TextView
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:text="@string/normal_text"
    />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/normalTextSpinner"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/normalTextSpinnerValues"
    />

    <TextView
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:text="@string/headings"
    />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/headingsSpinner"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:entries="@array/headingsSpinnerValues"
    />

    <TextView
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:text="@string/base_icon_size"
        android:textSize="14sp"
    />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/baseIconSizeSpinner"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:entries="@array/baseIconSizeSpinnerValues"
    />

    <TextView
        android:padding="5sp"
        android:text="@string/detailed_view"
        android:textSize="14sp"
    />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/detailedViewSpinnerValues"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/okButton"
    />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/exitButton"
    />
</GridLayout>
```

[image: Vista de pantalla con controles]

Comment: Dice el dicho, una imagen vale más que mil palabras, agrega también una imagen de lo que tienes y de lo que quieres.

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta incluyendo el código y la imagen.

Comment: gracias @CarlosErnestoVelázquez ahora es más entendible tu pregunta, por cierto, ¿Estas usando el emulador verdad?

Answer (score 1):

Lo que comentas es un error común en los emuladores.

El contenedor de todos los elementos, incluyendo los Spinner es el `GridLayout`, los `Spinner` no saldrían del área mostrada en pantalla, te sugiero pruebes en un dispositivo físico.

Si usas para tus `Spinner` la propiedad `android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"` este tomara todo el ancho del dispositivo, en este caso todo el ancho restante, se mostrarían de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en caso de no definir esta propiedad simplemente tomaran el ancho del elemento con mayor tamaño en la lista.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys, sin embargo dices que usando la propiedad `android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"` se completa, obviamente, todo el ancho del dispositivo restante, pero, ¿acaso el ancho del dispositivo no se circunscribe sólo al ancho de la pantalla del dispositivo (emulador)?. Entonces ¿no es posible diseñar con realismo una UI usando el Preview para ver cómo va quedando?  **NOTA:** Uso el emulador porque por alguna razón no puedo configurar ni el ADT ni el Android Studio para usar un dispositivo real (ya con la opción de desarrollador activa).